# URL /subdirectory match with port number

Tags: .htaccess, webserver, router

I would like to ask how to set in the webserver, APACHE.

eg. like cPanel webmail, user only need to enter

http://www.example.com/webmail then it will match with http://www.example.com:2095/

I not sure it is set with .htaccess or set it at router level.

Can anyone advice how to do this?

Comment: Something related with virtualhost can be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's called **Reverse Proxy** (even if you use it on the same server) : http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reverse_Proxy

It can be done on Apache using standard modules **mod_proxy** and **mod_rewrite**. I have not done it myself on Apache, so I cannot tell if mod_rewrite will actually be required here ... but a lot of examples I have seen utilizing functionality of both of them.

There really a lot of examples around -- you should have no issues finding them. Start at the following links:

- [mod_proxy Apache manual](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_proxy.html)
- [Using mod_rewrite for Proxying](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/proxy.html)